# Wordpress can't scroll down

Tags: php, html, wordpress, scroll, str-replace

My problem is that when a page loads on my wordpress site that I can't scroll down with the mousewheel.  I can pull the scroll bar down with the cursor.

I realized that I have a script built in to my index.php file (to help with some URL replacements) and when I take that script out that everything works fine and I can scroll again.

Is this a result of writing a script into index.php, or is my code in my script wrong, or is it a result of replacing the URL?

Comment: I just tried writing an empty script into the index.php and its still having the scrolling problem.  So apparently you can't write any scripts at all in index.php without a problem?  Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

I think some script in the index file conflicts with wordpress. Try removing the script you added in the wordpress and check it. Hope the problem will be solved.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  I'm trying to find out what is specifically wrong with it and correct it.  I need the script to stay.

Comment: <script>
$.noConflict();
</script> Try using jquery noConflict(); or move the script to the footer and check. You may over come

Answer (score 0):

Writing any script into the index.php page locked up my scroll bar.  So I installed the plugin "insert headers and footers" and added my script to the header.  Script still works and now the scroll bar does too.